# Unable to capture the html elements, while doing webscraping using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Unable to capture the html elements,  while doing webscraping using BeautifulSoup

I am running the below code in pycharm

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source=requests.get("https://twitter.com/SGanguly").text

soup=BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
print(soup.prettify())
```

The output contains no html elements to capture , it shows only errors in the tags instead of classes and
html elements

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=0,viewport-fit=cover" name="viewport"/>
  <style>
   body {
      -ms-overflow-style: scrollbar;
      overflow-y: scroll;
      overscroll-behavior-y: none;
    }

    .errorContainer {
      background-color: #FFF;
      color: #0F1419;
      max-width: 600px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 10%;
      font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-size: 16px;
    }

    .errorButton {
      margin: 3em 0;
    }

    .errorButton a {
      background: #1DA1F2;
      border-radius: 2.5em;
      color: white;
      padding: 1em 2em;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    .errorButton a:hover,
    .errorButton a:focus {
      background: rgb(26, 145, 218);
    }

    .errorFooter {
      color: #657786;
      font-size: 80%;
      line-height: 1.5;
      padding: 1em 0;
    }

    .errorFooter a,
    .errorFooter a:visited {
      color: #657786;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding-right: 1em;
    }

    .errorFooter a:hover,
    .errorFooter a:active {
      text-decoration: underline;
    }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="errorContainer">
   <img alt="Twitter" height="38" src="https://abs.twimg.com/errors/logo46x38.png" srcset="https://abs.twimg.com/errors/logo46x38.png 1x, https://abs.twimg.com/errors/logo46x38@2x.png 2x" width="46"/>
   <h1>
    This browser is no longer supported.
   </h1>
   <p>
    Please switch to a supported browser to continue using twitter.com. You can see a list of supported browsers in our Help Center.
   </p>
   <p class="errorButton">
    <a href="https://help.twitter.com/using-twitter/twitter-supported-browsers">
     Help Center
    </a>
   </p>
   <p class="errorFooter">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/tos">
     Terms of Service
    </a>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/privacy">
     Privacy Policy
    </a>
    <a href="https://support.twitter.com/articles/20170514">
     Cookie Policy
    </a>
    <a href="https://legal.twitter.com/imprint">
     Imprint
    </a>
    <a href="https://business.twitter.com/en/help/troubleshooting/how-twitter-ads-work.html">
     Ads info
    </a>
    © 2021 Twitter, Inc.
   </p>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The direct answer to your question is that you need to provide headers with at least a user-agent defined. However, twitter relies on javascript, so you still won't be able to use requests and beautifulsoup alone to scrape the data. You'll need something that is able to parse the javascript code as well. I personally use selenium, but there are other options as well.